# How to fix Selenium Error (Python) - Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

```
class Pinterest:
   def __init__(self, email: str, password: str) -> None:
    
    self.email = email  
    self.password = password 
    self.webdriver_path = os.path.abspath('assets/chromedriver.exe')
    self.driver = self.webdriver()  
    self.login_url = 'https://www.pinterest.com/login/'
    self.upload_url = 'https://www.pinterest.com/pin-builder/'

   def webdriver(self):
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  
    options.add_argument('--lang=en')  
    options.add_argument('log-level=3')  
    options.add_argument('--mute-audio')  
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(  
        self.webdriver_path), options=options) 
    driver.maximize_window()  
    return driver
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you create the chrome web driver using

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(self.webdriver_path),options=options)
```

the absolute path of the `chromewebdriver.exe` will be taken from `PATH` environment variable. In order to resolve this issue, you could either pass the path explicitly to the `webdriver.Chrome` class. ie,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="<FULL PATH OF .EXE>", service=Service(self.webdriver_path),options=options)
```

Or

Add the web driver path to the PATH environment variable